# C# IEnumerable to List error?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I got a simple IEnumerable with some data in my debugging session for StockSearchList. How do I convert to a List but ToList is not accespted.

```
public IEnumerable<StockSearchItemViewModel> StockSearchList
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_stockSearchFilter)) 
                    return _stockSearchList;

                var filterLower = _stockSearchFilter.ToLower();

                return _stockSearchList.Where(x => { var symbolLower = x.Symbol.ToLower(); return (symbolLower.StartsWith(filterLower) || symbolLower.StartsWith(filterLower)); });
            }
        }
```

In another method i got:

```
    List<StockTickerData> ssl = new List<StockTickerData>();
    ssl = StockSearchList<StockTickerData>.ToList();
```

But I get build error of:

```
Error   4   The property 'xxxx.StockViewModel.StockSearchList' cannot be used with type arguments   .... stockviewmodel.cs  838 19
```

How do I convert ssl to a be list from the values in StockTickerData
Thanks

Comment: `StockSearchList<StockTickerData>` where did that come from? It's nonsense syntax, and syntax can't be made up at random. You probably want something like `List<StockTickerData> ssl  = StockSearchList.Select(vm => SomeFunctionToConvertToData(vm)).ToList()` (although if it doesn't *need* to be a list that but can be skipped; still takes a conversion function). Or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a simple syntax error, the right code:

```
 List<StockTickerData> ssl = StockSearchList.ToList();
```